# How do I set a condition to remove a property from Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to remove the level_6 if counter !== maxCount, but it removes the level_6 on both "if" and "else".

```js
let maxCount = 5;
let counter = 1;

this.combinations = {
  level_1: [ [0] ],
  level_2: [ [0] ],
  level_3: [ [0] ],
  level_4: [ [0] ],
  level_5: [ [0] ],
  level_6: [ [0] ]
};

app.post("/get-level", CSRFHeaderSecurity.Init, (req, res) => {
  let level = req.body.level;

  if (level === 1) {
    if (counter === maxCount) {
      counter = 1;
    } else {
      counter++;
    }
    storage.setItem("counter", counter).then(() => {
      console.log(counter);
    });
  }

  if (counter === maxCount) {
    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        level: this.combinations[`level_${level}`]
      })
    );
  } else {
    delete this.combinations.level_6;
    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        level: this.combinations[`level_${level}`]
      })
    );
  }
});
```

I expect to get 5 combinations/levels if the counter is equal to 5, but if the counter is not equal to 5 i want the combonations/levels to remain 6

Comment: The only explanation is that `counter === maxCount` is not true. So, double check your logic because at some point `counter` is not reaching (or getting incremented over) the value of `maxCount`.

Comment: you set `counter` to 1 if it was equal to `maxCount` before you get to the second conditional, so it will never be equal to `maxCount` there. I'm assuming the request has a body.level that === 1.

Comment: @lealceldeiro Thank u for the response, the counter does equal to maxCount after the game has been played five times, basically every time it gets to level_1, it gets incremented, so I want on the 5th instance to have 6 levels, hope I made sense

Answer (score 0):

Your logic has an issue. level_6 get's deleted on level_1 if the counter reached the value of `maxCount`. This code block is the culprit:

```
if (level === 1) {
if (counter === maxCount) {
  counter = 1;
} else {
  counter++;
}
```